# m×n board におけるナイト・ツアーの数えあげを高速に行うには？

Tags: c, アルゴリズム

以前の質問（[n×n board におけるナイト・ツアーの数えあげについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16301/n%C3%97n-board-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%83%8A%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88-%E3%83%84%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E6%95%B0%E3%81%88%E3%81%82%E3%81%92%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)）
でナイトツアーの数えあげを行いました。

さて、一般に
m×n board におけるナイト・ツアーの数えあげを高速に行うには
どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

以下のコードは、長方形の対称性を利用することで以前の計算の約1/4位になっています。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int search(int x, int y, int w, int h, long long used, int depth){
  int cnt = 0;
  if (x < 0 || w <= x || y < 0 || h <= y || (used & (1LL << (x + y * w))) > 0) return 0;
  if (depth == w * h) return 1;
  used += 1LL << (x + y * w);
  cnt += search(x + 2, y - 1, w, h, used, depth + 1);
  cnt += search(x + 2, y + 1, w, h, used, depth + 1);
  cnt += search(x - 2, y - 1, w, h, used, depth + 1);
  cnt += search(x - 2, y + 1, w, h, used, depth + 1);
  cnt += search(x + 1, y - 2, w, h, used, depth + 1);
  cnt += search(x + 1, y + 2, w, h, used, depth + 1);
  cnt += search(x - 1, y - 2, w, h, used, depth + 1);
  cnt += search(x - 1, y + 2, w, h, used, depth + 1);
  used -= 1LL << (x + y * w);
  return cnt;
}

int directed_open_tours(int w, int h){
  int x;
  int y;
  long long used;
  int total = 0;
  for (y = 0; y < h / 2; y++){
    for (x = 0; x < w / 2; x++){
      used = 0LL;
      total += search(x, y, w, h, used, 1) * 4;
    }
    if (w % 2 == 1){
      x = w / 2;
      used = 0LL;
      total += search(x, y, w, h, used, 1) * 2;
    }
  }
  if (h % 2 == 1){
    y = h / 2;
    for (x = 0; x < w / 2; x++){
      used = 0LL;
      total += search(x, y, w, h, used, 1) * 2;
    }
    if (w % 2 == 1){
      x = w / 2;
      used = 0LL;
      total += search(x, y, w, h, used, 1) * 1;
    }   
  }
  return total;
}

int main(void){
  int w;
  int h;
  printf("%d\n", directed_open_tours(4, 5));
  printf("%d\n", directed_open_tours(5, 4));
  printf("%d\n", directed_open_tours(4, 6));
  printf("%d\n", directed_open_tours(6, 4));
  printf("%d\n", directed_open_tours(4, 7));
  printf("%d\n", directed_open_tours(7, 4));
  return 0;
}
```

実行結果
164
164
1488
1488
12756
12756

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 盤面の対称性を利用する

元質問での工夫にもある通り、縦横半分に4分割すると、それぞれ線対称・点対称の関係にありますので、各部分の解の数は同数になります。そのため、 1/4 の部分の各マスを始点とした解の数の合計を求めて4倍すると全体の解が求まります。
ただし、辺の長さが奇数の場合は工夫が必要です。中央の一列は、上記の 1/4 の部分の計算に含めず、後から改めて求めるとよいです。

1. 縦 / 2 × 横 / 2 (それぞれ切り捨て) の部分について、各マスを始点とした解の数を求め、それを4倍する。
2. 縦の数が奇数の場合、その中央の列について、横の半分 (切り捨て) までの各マスを始点とした解の数を求め、それを2倍する。
3. 横の数が奇数の場合も縦横を読み替えて同様にする。
4. 縦、横共に奇数の場合、これまでの手順で、中央の1マスが未計算になるので、中央のマスを始点とした解の数を求める。
5. 上記すべてを合計する。

### 各マスから/各マスへ飛べる未訪問のマス数を用いて枝刈りを行う

元のコードでは、各マスを既に訪問したか否かだけを管理していますが、マス毎に、そのマスに到達できる、あるいはそこから飛べる未訪問のマスの数 (*) を管理することで枝刈りを行えます。

(*) 言い替えると、各マスをノードとし、ナイトが1回移動できるマス間を繋いだ双方向グラフの、ノードから延びる辺の数です。
例えば、5x5 の盤面の、まだどこにも訪問していない状態での数は以下のようになります。

```
+--+--+--+--+--+
| 2| 3| 4| 3| 2|
+--+--+--+--+--+
| 3| 4| 6| 4| 2|
+--+--+--+--+--+
| 4| 6| 8| 6| 4|
+--+--+--+--+--+
| 3| 4| 6| 4| 2|
+--+--+--+--+--+
| 2| 3| 4| 3| 2|
+--+--+--+--+--+
```

今回考えついた、カウントを元にした枝刈りの方法は以下の通りです。

まず、解の探索のために、あるマスを訪問して、それによってそこから飛べるマスのカウントを減らします。
その時の状態によって、以下のように枝刈りを行います。

#### 飛び先候補のマスで、カウントが0になったマスがあったら、それが最後の未訪問マスでなければ、その探索は失敗。

次の飛び先として、カウントが0のマスを選んだら、それ以上移動できなくなります。かといって、他のマスを優先すると、カウント0のマスに入ることができなくなります。
そのため、カウントが0となった場合、それが最後の未訪問マスでなければ失敗となります。

#### 盤面全体で、カウントが1のマスが3つ以上あったら、その探索は失敗。

カウント1のマスとは、そこに飛び込んだら、もうそれ以上移動できなくなるマスのことです。
つまり、そこを最後の訪問先としなくてはなりません。
それだけなら、3つ以上ではなく、2つ以上の時点で失敗ですが、現在の訪問先からカウント1のマスに飛んだ場合はまだ移動できるので詰みません。3つの場合は、現在の訪問先からそのうちひとつに飛べたとしても、残りふたつを同時に最後にすることはできないため詰みます。

#### カウントが1のマスが2つの場合、次の飛び先は必ずカウント1のマスのみとする。

ひとつ前の枝刈りでも説明した通り、カウント1のマスが2つ存在した時点で探索失敗となりますが、現在の訪問先からカウント1のマスに飛べばまだ目があります。逆に言うと、カウント1以外のマスに飛んでしまうと、ふたつのマスを同時に最後にする必要が出てきてしまうので解がなくなります。

### コード

以上の工夫を取り入れたプログラムを書いてみました。無闇に煩雑で長々としているのは私のセンスのなさゆえですが大目に見て下さい。
また、1 x 1 の結果が 0 となるバグがあります。1 x 1だけ特別扱いすればよいだけではありますが……

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>


struct board {
    // 盤面の大きさ
    int num_rows, num_cols;

     //counts[行インデックス][列インデックス]:
     //そのマスから/マスへ移動可能なマスがいくつあるか。
     //解の探索で、利き筋のマスが訪問済になると減少する。
     //また、訪問済のマスは -1 とする。
    int **counts;

    // カウントが1のマスの数。これが3以上になると
    // そのすべてを訪問することはできないため解なしとなる。
    int num_ones;
};


// マスの位置を表す構造体。
struct board_index {
    int row, col;
};


// ナイトの利き筋。
const struct board_index g_knight_movement[] = {
    { 1,  2}, {-1,  2}, { 1, -2}, {-1, -2},
    { 2,  1}, {-2,  1}, { 2, -1}, {-2, -1},
};
// g_knight_movement の要素数。
#define NUM_KNIGHT_MOVEMENTS  ((sizeof(g_knight_movement) / sizeof(g_knight_movement[0])))


// 指定されたインデックスが盤面の範囲に入っているか。
inline static bool in_board(const struct board *restrict brd, struct board_index index)
{
    return ((0 <= index.row) && (index.row < brd->num_rows))
        && ((0 <= index.col) && (index.col < brd->num_cols));
}


// 指定したマスの利き筋の数の初期値を求める。
int initial_count_at(const struct board *restrict brd, int row, int col)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < NUM_KNIGHT_MOVEMENTS; i++) {
        struct board_index next = { // (row, col) から一回動いた位置
            .row = g_knight_movement[i].row + row,
            .col = g_knight_movement[i].col + col,
        };
        count += in_board(brd, next);
    }
    return count;
}


// init_board_result() の戻り値。
enum init_board_result {
    IB_SUCCESS,         // 初期化成功
    IB_ERROR,           // エラー発生
    IB_NO_SOLUTION,     // 初期化時に解がないことが確定して初期化を中断した
};


// 盤面の情報を初期化する。
enum init_board_result init_board(struct board *restrict brd, int num_rows, int num_cols)
{
    enum init_board_result err_retval;
    brd->num_rows = num_rows;
    brd->num_cols = num_cols;
    brd->num_ones = 0;
    brd->counts = (int **)malloc(sizeof(brd->counts[0]) * num_rows);
    if(brd->counts == NULL) {
        err_retval = IB_ERROR;
        goto err_alloc_baseptr;
    }
    int row;
    for(row = 0; row < num_rows; row++) {
        brd->counts[row] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(brd->counts[0][0]) * num_cols);
        if(brd->counts[row] == NULL) {
            err_retval = IB_ERROR;
            goto err_alloc_row;
        }
        for(int col = 0; col < num_cols; col++) {
            brd->counts[row][col] = initial_count_at(brd, row, col);
            switch(brd->counts[row][col]) {
            case 1:
                brd->num_ones++;
                break;

            case 0:
                err_retval = IB_NO_SOLUTION;
                goto no_solution;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return IB_SUCCESS;

    // error or no solution
no_solution:
    free(brd->counts[row]);
err_alloc_row:
    while(row-- > 0) {
        free(brd->counts[row]);
    }
    free(brd->counts);
err_alloc_baseptr:
    return err_retval;
}


// 盤面を破棄する。
void destray_board(struct board *restrict brd)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < brd->num_rows; row++) {
        free(brd->counts[row]);
    }
    free(brd->counts);
}


// 後述の update_next_counts_and_enum_available_indices() とペアで使う。
// 上記関数で列挙されたマスのカウントを元に戻す。
void restore_next_counts(
    struct board *restrict brd,
    const struct board_index nexts[restrict],
    size_t num_nexts)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < num_nexts; i++) {
        // カウント戻し + 1のマス数の調整
        switch(brd->counts[nexts[i].row][nexts[i].col]++) {
        case 1:
            brd->num_ones--;
            break;

        case 0:
            brd->num_ones++;
            break;
        }
    }
}


// 現在位置から到達できるマスのカウントを減らしつつ、
// 指定された位置から次に動ける候補一覧を列挙する。
// nexts[] に候補が格納され、候補数が返される。解がないと判断されたら
// カウントの変更はキャンセルされ、0が返されら。
size_t update_next_counts_and_enum_available_indices(
    struct board *restrict brd,
    struct board_index index,
    bool is_last_step,
    struct board_index nexts[restrict])
{
    size_t num_nexts = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < NUM_KNIGHT_MOVEMENTS; i++) {
        struct board_index next = {
            .row = g_knight_movement[i].row + index.row,
            .col = g_knight_movement[i].col + index.col,
        };
        if(!in_board(brd, next)) {
            // 盤面の範囲外は候補たり得ないので何もしない
            continue;
        }
        int count = brd->counts[next.row][next.col];
        if(count < 0) {
            // 訪問済のマスは触らない。
            continue;
        }
        // 以降、すべて正の数となる。(0となるパターンは存在しない)
        assert(count != 0);
        // カウントを減らす。
        brd->counts[next.row][next.col] = count - 1;
        if(count == 1) {
            // 1のマス (今回0になった) が見付かった時点で、それが唯一の候補。
            // ただし、それが最後の空きマスでなければ、さらに
            // 次の一歩を移動できないので解なしとなる。
            if(is_last_step) {
                num_nexts = 1;
                nexts[0] = next;
                brd->num_ones--;
                // 他のマスはすべて訪問済なので、これ以上見る必要はない。
                break;
            }
            else {
                // 解なし。変更を元に戻して0を返す。
                brd->counts[next.row][next.col] = count;
                restore_next_counts(brd, nexts, num_nexts);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            nexts[num_nexts++] = next;
            if(count == 2) {
                // 減算の結果、1になるので、記録してある1の数を増やす。
                brd->num_ones++;
            }
        }
    }
    assert(num_nexts > 0);
    return num_nexts;
}


long long solve_knight_tour_impl(
    struct board *restrict brd,
    int depth,
    struct board_index index)
{
    if(depth == brd->num_rows * brd->num_cols - 1) {
        // 解がひとつ見付かった
        return 1;
    }

    struct board_index nexts[NUM_KNIGHT_MOVEMENTS]; // 移動先候補は最大でナイトの利き筋の数。
    size_t num_nexts = update_next_counts_and_enum_available_indices(
                            brd, index,
                            depth == brd->num_rows * brd->num_cols - 2,
                            nexts);
    if(num_nexts == 0) {
        // この探索では解がない。
        return 0;
    }
    // 現在位置を無効化する。
    // 後で戻せるように値の退避もしておく。
    int saved_count = brd->counts[index.row][index.col];
    if(saved_count == 1) {
        brd->num_ones--;
    }
    brd->counts[index.row][index.col] = -1;

    long long found = 0;
    // ここで、現在の1のマスの数を調べる。
    if(brd->num_ones >= 3) {
        // 3以上なら解なしとなるので何もしない。
    }
    else {
        if(brd->num_ones >= 2) {
            // カウントが1の移動先候補それぞれについて解を探索。
            for(size_t i = 0; i < num_nexts; i++) {
                if(brd->counts[nexts[i].row][nexts[i].col] == 1) {
                    found += solve_knight_tour_impl(brd, depth + 1, nexts[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // 移動先候補それぞれについて解を探索。
            for(size_t i = 0; i < num_nexts; i++) {
                found += solve_knight_tour_impl(brd, depth + 1, nexts[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    // [A] の変更元に戻す。
    brd->counts[index.row][index.col] = saved_count;
    if(saved_count == 1) {
        brd->num_ones++;
    }
    restore_next_counts(brd, nexts, num_nexts);

    return found;
}


// num_rows × num_cols の盤面のナイトツアーを満たす解の数を返す。
// エラー発生時は -1 。
// なお、回転・線対称・逆周りはすべて別個の解として数えている。
long long solve_knight_tour(size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols)
{
    struct board brd;
    switch(init_board(&brd, num_rows, num_cols)) {
    case IB_SUCCESS:
        break;

    case IB_ERROR:
        return -1;

    case IB_NO_SOLUTION:
        return 0;
    }
    long long found = 0;

    // 各座標を視点とした解の個数を合計する。
    // なお、縦横2等分すれば、それぞれ線対称の位置になるので、
    // その 1/4 の部分だけ計算し、4倍することで全体の結果が求められる。
    // ただし、奇数の場合は、中央の行・列の追加計算も必要。
    for(int row = 0; row < num_rows / 2; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < num_cols / 2; col++) {
            found += solve_knight_tour_impl(&brd, 0, (struct board_index){ .row = row, .col = col });
        }
    }
    found *= 4;
    // 奇数の場合の追加パターン
    if(num_rows & 1) {
        long long extra_found = 0;
        // 行数が奇数 → 真ん中の行を追加計算。これも半分だけ計算して2倍する。
        for(int col = 0; col < num_cols / 2; col++) {
            extra_found += solve_knight_tour_impl(&brd, 0, (struct board_index){ .row = num_rows / 2, .col = col });
        }
        found += extra_found * 2;
    }
    if(num_cols & 1) {
        long long extra_found = 0;
        // 列数が奇数 → 真ん中の列を追加計算。これも半分だけ計算して2倍する。
        for(int row = 0; row < num_rows / 2; row++) {
            extra_found += solve_knight_tour_impl(&brd, 0, (struct board_index){ .row = row, .col = num_cols / 2 });
        }
        found += extra_found * 2;
    }
    if((num_rows & 1) && (num_cols & 1)) {
        // どちらも奇数 → 中央のマスを追加計算。
        found += solve_knight_tour_impl(&brd, 0, (struct board_index){ .row = num_rows / 2, .col = num_cols / 2 });
    }
    destray_board(&brd);
    return found;
}


// 引数に盤面のサイズを指定する。
// 不正な引数が渡された場合のエラー処理はしていない(手抜き)。
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s #-rows #-cols\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int num_rows = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    int num_cols = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);

    // 探索本体
    long long num_solutions = solve_knight_tour(num_rows, num_cols);
    if(num_solutions == -1) {
        perror("");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("# of solutions = %lld\n", num_solutions);
    return 0;
}
```

### 実行結果

#### 環境

- CPU: Core i5 2520M (2.50Ghz)
- OS: Gentoo Linux (カーネル 4.0.5)
- コンパイラ: gcc-4.8.5

#### コンパイル & 実行

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c11 -O3 -march=native -mtune=native knight-tour.c 
$ for arg in "4 5" "5 4" "4 6" "6 4" "4 7" "7 4" "6 6"; do echo "$arg:"; time ./a.out $arg; echo; echo; done 
4 5:
# of solutions = 164

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s


5 4:
# of solutions = 164

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s


4 6:
# of solutions = 1488

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s


6 4:
# of solutions = 1488

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s


4 7:
# of solutions = 12756

real    0m0.016s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s


7 4:
# of solutions = 12756

real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.000s


6 6:
# of solutions = 6637920

real    0m3.978s
user    0m3.976s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: コンパイルしようとすると以下のようなエラーが出ます。
20150912.c(39) : error C2054: 'inline' の後に '(' が必要です。
20150912.c(39) : error C2146: 構文エラー : ')' が、識別子 'brd' の前に必要です。
20150912.c(39) : error C2085: 'in_board' : 仮パラメーター リスト内にありません。
20150912.c(39) : error C2146: 構文エラー : ',' が、識別子 'brd' の前に必要です。
20150912.c(39) : error C2059: 構文エラー : '型'
20150912.c(39) : error C2059: 構文エラー : ')'
20150912.c(47) : error C2146: 構文エラー : ')' が、識別子 'brd' の前に必要です。
20150912.c(47) : error C2061: 構文エラー : 識別子 'brd'
20150912.c(47) : error C2059: 構文エラー : ';'
20150912.c(47) : error C2059: 構文エラー : ','
20150912.c(47) : error C2059: 構文エラー : ')'
（以下　略）

Comment: 最適化を期待したのと横着のために、C99以降の文法を使っていますが、Visual Studioではサポートされない文法が含まれています。VS2013では、 `inline` と `restrict` を単純に削除することでコンパイルが通りました。

Comment: コンパイラのバージョンによっては、(1) 各種構造体初期化子の中の `{ .メンバ名 = 初期値 }`、(2) `solve_knight_tour()` 内の `solve_knight_tour_impl()` 呼び出しにおける、`(struct board_index){ ... }` 、(3) `<stdbool.h>` 関連処理 でもエラーが発生するかもしれません。それぞれ以下のように対処して下さい。(1) → `.メンバ名 =` を削除する。こうすると、メンバの並び順に気を着ける必要がありますが、今回は単純に削除するだけでOKになっているはずです。(2) → `struct board_index` 型の一時変数を用意して、引数にしたい値で初期化する。`solve_knight_tour_impl()` の引数には、その一時変数を渡す。(3) → `#include <stdbool.h>` を削除し、`typedef enum { false, true} bool; ` を先頭付近で宣言しておく。

Comment: inline と restrict を単純に削除することでコンパイルが通りました。

Comment: （度々申し訳ございません。）VS2013で20150912.exe 4 5 と逐次実行するのではなく、$ for arg in "4 5" "5 4" "4 6" "6 4" "4 7" "7 4" "6 6"; do echo "$arg:"; time ./a.out $arg; echo; echo; done 
4 5:のように行うにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: Windowsのコマンドプロンプトについては詳しくないので方法が思い付きません。代案として、[Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/)を入れて、 bash を使えるようにするという手があります (for ... done は bash の文法です)。Cygwinを直接インストールする代わりに、[MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)のポータブル版を使うのが手っ取り早いかと。

Answer (score 3):

**（質問した経緯）**
http://magictour.free.fr/enum
上記サイトにm×n board におけるナイト・ツアーの数が正しいものと不明なものを含めて載っているのですが、
**3×16の場合に誤りがある**※ことに一週間ほど前気づき質問させていただきました。
※正しい結果自体は以下に投稿したが、投稿するコミュニティを間違っていたため今は保留中になっています。
(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426623/how-many-open-knights-tours-are-possible-in-a-3%C3%9716-chessboard)

**（yoh2 さんのコードによるナイトツアーの数えあげの結果）**
m = 4, 5のときはOEISに十分なほど載っているので、
m = 3, 6, 7のときについて載せておきます。

m = 3のとき

```
C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 1
# of solutions = 0

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 2
# of solutions = 0

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 3
# of solutions = 0

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 4
# of solutions = 16

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 5
# of solutions = 0

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 6
# of solutions = 0

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 7
# of solutions = 104

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 8
# of solutions = 792

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 9
# of solutions = 1120

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 10
# of solutions = 6096

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 11
# of solutions = 21344

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 12
# of solutions = 114496

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 13
# of solutions = 257728

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 14
# of solutions = 1292544

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 15
# of solutions = 3677568

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 16
# of solutions = 17273760

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 17
# of solutions = 46801984

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 18
# of solutions = 211731376

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 19
# of solutions = 611507360

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 20
# of solutions = 2645699504

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 3 21
# of solutions = 7725948608
```

m = 6のとき

```
C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 6 1
# of solutions = 0

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 6 2
# of solutions = 0

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 6 3
# of solutions = 0

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 6 4
# of solutions = 1488

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 6 5
# of solutions = 37568

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 6 6
# of solutions = 6637920

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 6 7
# of solutions = 779938932
```

m = 7のとき

```
C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 7 1
# of solutions = 0

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 7 2
# of solutions = 0

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 7 3
# of solutions = 104

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 7 4
# of solutions = 12756

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 7 5
# of solutions = 1245736

C:\Users\Seiichi>20150912.exe 7 6
# of solutions = 779938932
```

Comment: ちなみにm = 3のとき、OEISもMathWorldも今のところnが13以下の場合しか載っていない。

Comment: m = 3のときは計算アルゴリズムが存在していたので、実装し以下の記事を更新しました。(https://oeis.org/A118067)